# How can I match conditions when I show arp?

Tags: cisco, arp

In my Cisco Router I check the arp:

```
Router>show arp 
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.1.1             -   0001.42D2.AE01  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0/0
Internet  192.168.1.2             67  000C.CF4C.99E6  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0/0
Internet  192.168.2.1             -   0001.42D2.AE02  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0/1
Internet  192.168.2.2             109 0010.114E.A4EC  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0/1
```

I want to match conditions, but I tried bellow, all do not work:

```
Router>show arp | match 192.168.2.2
                ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Router>show arp 192.168.2.2
                ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

---

I also tried the begin, or include:

```
Router#show arp | begin ?
% Unrecognized command
```

---

**UPDATE**

The `show version` display this:

```
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 03.16.05.S - Extended Support Release
Cisco IOS Software, ISR Software (X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version Version 15.5 (3)S5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
```

this is a ISR 4321 Router.

Comment: You need to be in config mode, then `sh arp | in 192.168.2.2`

Comment: @Cown hi are you certain about that? `gw(config)#sh arp ?` => `% Unrecognized command`, tested on IOS 15.2(4)M3 just now.

Comment: Sorry not config mode, enable mode.

Comment: HI @cown are you certain about that too?  Copy/paste in my answer was done in disable exactly as shown.

Comment: @jonathanjo but if he uses packet tracer i think you need to be in enable mode if i remember, but i sometimes dont.. hehe

Comment: `command | match somehing` is used in Juniper. In Cisco it's `command | i something`

Comment: What router is this?

Comment: Hi three-blocks did you try `enable` as Cown suggested?

Comment: Ok i can see the version, but what model is it? I might have one available to test on.

Comment: Ok i found the error i think, you need to use `show ip arp | in 192.168.2.2`

Comment: Did it work with `show ip arp`?

Comment: So did the `show ip arp` work instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For most varieties of Cisco IOS.**  (For the ISR 4321 it appears the answer is different, see later.)

To start with matching, use `| begin`:

```
gw>show arp | begin 192.168.0.32
Internet  192.168.0.32            0   90fb.a630.1234  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  192.168.0.36            0   0004.2012.4321  ARPA   Vlan1
...
```

There are a few varieties:

```
gw>show arp | ?
  begin    Begin with the line that matches
  count    Count number of lines which match regexp
  exclude  Exclude lines that match
  format   Format the output using the specified spec file
  include  Include lines that match
  section  Filter a section of output
```

But there's something funny going on if you can't do the basic:

```
gw>show arp 192.168.0.32
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.0.32            0   90fb.a630.1234  ARPA   Vlan1
```

What model and version are you using?

**ISR-4321**

Per Cown's comment:

> Ok i found the error i think, you need to use show ip arp | in 192.168.2.2

**Packet tracer**

As suggested by Cown in comments, if you're using Packet Tracer, not a real router, you have to be in enable mode.

Comment: Yeah same output i get here, just a bit more options, since it's a 6500 series.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mention command to match  ARP  association with the ip address

`Layer3device(config)#sh ip arp | i 192.168.2.2`

If you wants to display all ARP table on device use the fallowing command

`Layer3device(config)#Sh ip arp`

From this list of ARP table . Specific ip address and associated mac -address is visible.